# SyntaxError: missing ; before statement - no obvious error?

Tags: javascript, php

I keep getting the above error referring to the second line of my code below and have no idea why! With the below part removed my project works ok with no problems but I keep gettig that error with it in, hence it wont run.

```
      <?php 
       $myVar = $_POST['dropdown'];
       ?>
       <script type="text/javascript">
       var myVar = <?php echo '$myVar';?>
       console.log(myVar);
       </script>
```

Comment: variables aren't parsed in single quotes

Comment: You need a semi-colon after you close the PHP tag to close the JavaScript line.

Comment: either $myVar or "$myVar".

Comment: *You're leading by a nose Sam!* @JayBlanchard

Comment: Depending on what it contains, `<?= json_encode($myvar); ?>` might work better.

Comment: *Only because mine is so big Ralph!* @Fred-ii-

Comment: LMHO Sam! @JayBlanchard Ok... the "nose", right?

Comment: *Uh....yeah Ralph....the nose....* @Fred-ii-

Comment: *...and here I thought it was your "heart" Sam* @JayBlanchard All together now folks... *Aaawwwww.....!*

Comment: *Well played Ralph. Well played.* @Fred-ii-

Comment: ...what just happened...

Comment: @JonStirling A freight train went by...

Answer (score 0):

This is probably your issue

```
var myVar = <?php echo '$myVar';?>
```

This should work, assuming you did want the single quotes around the PHP variable, and this also contains the javascript end-of-statement `;` :

```
var myVar = <?php echo "'$myVar';";?>
```

If you did not want the single quotes then this should do :

```
var myVar = <?php echo $myVar . ';';?>
```